# Function pointer assignment, why does calling this function via pointer result in seg fault?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have this struct defined:

```
typedef struct Socket_s
{
  ...
  SocketConnectFunc         Connect;
  ...
}Socket;
```

where SocketConnectFunc is defined as:

```
typedef Socket_Return (*SocketConnectFunc) (void * self);
```

When initialising a Socket structure, I call this:

```
void Init(Socket * sock)
{
    sock = (Socket *)malloc(sizof(Socket));
    if(sock)
      sock->Connect = SocketConnect;
}
```

But then, when I attempt to call `sock->Connect()` I get segmentation fault, and the function isn't even entered. Is there a problem in the way I assigned `sock->Connect`?

NB. Socket_Return is an enum (`typedef enum {SUCCESS,FAIL} Socket_Return`)

Comment: I think its because the Init prototype needs to be `void Init(Socket ** sock)`. Otherwise the `sock` pointer is simply not altered, since it's being passed in by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the address of the pointer. Passing just the pointer you can't change it in the caller

```
void Init(Socket ** sock) {
    *sock = malloc(sizeof **sock); /* don't cast the return value of malloc! */
    if (*sock)
        (*sock)->connect = SocketConnect;
}
```

And call it like so

```
struct Socket_s *mysock;
Init(&mysock);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would write it like this:

```
Socket * CreateSocket() {
    Socket * sock = (Socket *) malloc( sizeof( Socket ) );
    if ( sock ) {
      sock->Connect = SocketConnect;
    }
    return sock;
}
```